# I have got syntax error after submitting the program i.e.," UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD". can anyone help on this

Tags: jcl

```
 //VENKATBK JOB (2222),'KRRISH',                  
 // TIME=(2,1),PRTY=0,CLASS=A,NOTIFY=VENKATB      
 //STEP1 EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                         
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                           
 //SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*                             
 //SYSUT1 DD DSN=VENKATB.KK.INPUT.COPY,DISP=SHR   
 //SYSUT2  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=VENKATB.KK.OUTPUT.COPY 
 //SYSIN DD*                                      
   COPY INDD=SYSUT1,                              
        OUTDD=SYSUT2                              
 /*                                               
 //
```

the message I have received from spool is.,

```
 STMT NO. MESSAGE                              
        7 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD
```

I have tried in many ways but I not able to find the root cause of above program

Comment: Have a look at the SYSIN DD stratement. There should be a space between the DD and *.  Change `//SYSIN DD*  ` to `//SYSIN DD *  `

Answer (score 2):

## z/OS MVS JCL line numbers and JCL Statement numbers

If our're working with `JCL` it is important to understand the difference between

- *Line numbers* as seen in the editor when writing the JCL statements.

and

- *Statements numbers* as seen in the *job log* after submitting the job.

JCL statements often consist of *multiple lines*.

### Line numbers in the editor

In the editor, the line number is increased for each line, no matter whether this is a complete JCL statement, a continuation line of a statement started on a previous line, or a comment statement.

An Example:

```
EDIT       Z08593.JCL(TEST) - 01.00                                Columns 00001 00080  
Command ===>                                                          Scroll ===> CSR   
****** ********************************* Top of Data ********************************** 
000001 //Z08593A  JOB 1,'phun@gmx.ch',                                                  
000002 //             CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=H,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                                
000003 //             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                                    
000004 //***************************************************/                           
000005 //STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                                                      
000006 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                           
000007 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                           
000008 //SYSUT1   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Z08593.INPUT                                           
000009 //SYSUT2   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Z08593.OUTPUT                                         
000010 //SYSIN    DD*                                                                   
000011   COPY INDD=SYSUT1,                                                              
000012        OUTDD=SYSUT2                                                              
000013 /*                                                                               
000014 //                                                                               
****** ******************************** Bottom of Data ********************************
```

### Statement numbers in the Job Log

In the job log, *complete JCL statements* are numbered, not individual lines as submitted. After submitting above sample JCL, there is a JCL error. The job log looks as follows:

#### The First Job Log File is JESMSGLOG

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA ***************************************************
                   J E S 2  J O B  L O G  --  S Y S T E M  S 0 W 1  --  N O D E  S V S C J E S 2 
                                                                                                 
16.08.17 JOB06871 ---- SUNDAY,    25 DEC 2022 ----                                               
16.08.17 JOB06871  IRR010I  USERID Z08593   IS ASSIGNED TO THIS JOB.                             
16.08.17 JOB06871  IEFC452I Z08593A - JOB NOT RUN - JCL ERROR  219                               
------ JES2 JOB STATISTICS ------                                                                
           13 CARDS READ                                                                         
           26 SYSOUT PRINT RECORDS                                                               
            0 SYSOUT PUNCH RECORDS                                                               
            1 SYSOUT SPOOL KBYTES                                                                
         0.00 MINUTES EXECUTION TIME                                                             
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA *************************************************
```

The line

```
16.08.17 JOB06871  IEFC452I Z08593A - JOB NOT RUN - JCL ERROR  219
```

tells you, that the job was not run because of one or more errors.

#### The Second Job Log File is JESJCL

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA *********************************************************
        1 //Z08593A  JOB 1,'phun@gmx.ch',                                         JOB06871             
          //             CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=H,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                                            
          //             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                                                
          //***************************************************/                                       
          IEFC653I SUBSTITUTION JCL - 1,'phun@gmx.ch',CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=H,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=Z08593  
        2 //STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                                                                  
        3 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                                       
        4 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                                       
        5 //SYSUT1   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Z08593.INPUT                                                       
        6 //SYSUT2   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Z08593.OUTPUT                                                     
        7 //SYSIN    DD*                                                                               
        8 //SYSIN     DD *               GENERATED STATEMENT                                           
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA *******************************************************
```

Note that there are only statement numbers from 1 to 8, compared to the 14 lines in the editor. It's **not** lines, it's **complete statements** which are numbered here. Ignoring comment lines.

#### The Third job Log File is JESYSMSG

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
 STMT NO. MESSAGE                                                               
        7 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD                                 
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

The first line reads `STMT NO. MESSAGE`. The following line or lines show informational messages, warnings, and, in this case, the error message.

So, *statement number 7* is in error. So the interpreter did not recoginze *what it considers to be the operation field*! Carefully look the message and understand what this tells you: There seems to be some text on *statement* number 7 which *should be* the operation (JOB, EXEC, DD, are some of the operations), **but** the interpreter does not know it.

Go back to the second file in the joblog, search *statement number 7* and have a look. A JCL statement

- starts with `//`
- followed by the (optional) *statement name* (or name field),
- followed by one or more blanks,
- followed by the *operation* (or operation field),
- followed by one or more blanks,
- (optionally) followed by one or more parameters,
- followed by one or more blanks,
- (optionally) followed by comment

Statement 7 looks like this:

```
        7 //SYSIN    DD*
```

"7" is the statement number. The actual JCL text starts with `//` followed by the name `SYSIN`, followed by the operation `DD*`. There is no operation called `DD*`. You see the problem? There is a space missing between the operation `DD`, and its single parameter `*`.

If you were reading the error message, then immediately switched back to the editor, and looked for *line number 7*, you'd find line

```
000007 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
```

and ask yourself what's wrong here. Nothing, it's simply *not* the statment in error.

#### Generated Statement

Did you recognize statement number 8 in the second job log file? No? It reads like this:

```
        8 //SYSIN     DD *               GENERATED STATEMENT
```

But wait a minute, there is no second `//SYSIN` statement in the JCL source (in the editor), so where does this come from?

This job's JCL has some commands for program `IEBCOPY`, which are written *in-line* with the JCL. This is also called *instream data*, or *sysin data*.

```
000011   COPY INDD=SYSUT1,    
000012        OUTDD=SYSUT2
```

This data is set aside for later reading via the `DD *` statement that preceeds it. You meant to write `//SYSIN DD *`, but you wrote `//SYSIN DD*` which was not recognized. So the interpreter has no `DD *` statement to associate the sysin data with, thus it *generates* one! This generated statement *always* looks like this

```
//SYSIN     DD *
```

To help you detect it, the comment `GENERATED STATEMENT` is added to the statement.
So if you read `GENERATED STATEMENT` on a `DD` statement, take is as warning; there probably is something wrong with your JCL, not necessarily a syntax error, though.

*Note* the fact that both statements are named `SYSIN` is pure coincidence. If the statement in error would read `//INPUT DD*`, the generated statement would still be `//SYSIN     DD *`.